# Would it be possible to discard a numeric string (string only containing numbers) from a set in python?

Tags: python, set

E.g. The set is:

```
{'abc', '123', 'efg', 'er23'}
```

I would like to get rid of only the '123' from the set. Would it be possible in python?

Comment: `{s for s in your_set if not isinstance(s, int)}` is one way.

Comment: @Maroun `isinstance` will not work as the item is a string.

Comment: @Xnkr you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
s={'abc', '123', 'efg', 'er23'}
print({i for i in s if not i.isdigit()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can do it with this way this will only remove element that only digit

```
data = {'abc', '123', 'efg', 'er23'}
new_items = [item for item in data if not item.isdigit()]
print new_items
```